# Codeigniter Transfer data table to table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to insert data from a table in MySql to other table , but I need to insert a new key before , so I tried this:

```
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        $prodId = $this->db->insert_id();
        $this->db->from('tmp_prod_icms');
        $this->db->where('CADKEY', $this->session->userdata('key'));
        $tmpICMS = $this->db->get()->result();
        foreach($tmpICMS as $r) { // loop over results
            $r["CADPROCOD"] = $prodId;
            $this->db->insert('prod_icms', $r); 
        }            
        $this->db->trans_complete();
```

But when I try to insert the key "CADPROCOD" the app just stops, don't give even a error, just stops

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the logs? In the MySQL ones you should most likely find the error and why it fails.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, I debug the code, and It stops in that line -> "$r["CADPROCOD"] = $prodId;". So, I think that is not a MySql problem.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it with CI's error mode? `if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
        // generate an error... or use the log_message() function to log your error
}`

Comment: I do this and the status of the transaction is not FALSE, so it works like normal, right? I think that I make some mistake with the array

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I use $tmpICMS = $this->db->get()->result();
And this return a object, so I can't manipulate this like a Array, so i just need to change for $tmpICMS = $this->db->get()->result_array();
So this work for me